# MergeAdapter and hiding headers (views)

Tags: android-listview, header, android-arrayadapter, commonsware-cwac

I have three adapters and headers before each adapter in a listView. If a particular section is empty, how can I hide that header(view)?

It leaves a space where it is if I make it's layout visibility gone.

Comment: Um, don't put the header there in the first place, if the section is empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have to put the headers , then adapter, all in order... so it has to be put there... If I don't add them in order, they don't show up in the correct order... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! :-)

```
                mergeAdapter.setActive(songHeaderView, false);
```

So simple!